# Create dynamic table in layout view (Arcmap)

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, layouts, dynamic-tables

I want to add an attribute table to my layout view in Arcmap 10.1. I only want some columns and I have made a few other customizations. However, some attributes might change along the way and I don't feel like adding the table all over again each time it does, since there's a lot of tideous work with hiding and unhiding columns and whatever else I might do to it.

How can I create a dynamic table in my layout view which updates automagically when I change values in the source table? There are descriptions about how to create tables that only displays features that are currently in the visible extent ([like here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32544/is-it-possible-to-have-a-dynamic-table-in-a-data-driven-page-environment)). But that's not what I'm looking for.

I would think this is something that someone else would've wanted, so I hope there's an easy solution out there! (Preferably not involving programming/Python, unless it's the only way to do it...)

Comment: I disagree that this would be a duplicate, since I'm not interested in only displaying values that are in certain extents. What I want is to add a table to my layout view that updates corresponding cells when I update my attributes in the table (i.e. not adding the table as an image object but having it linked to the actual table). But if that is the only answer, I guess this question has no value and should be closed.

Comment: The Question incorporates DDP as well which means it is really a superset of yours.  It is the @RyanDalton Answer that seems to cover your Question more precisely.  I would be open to the new question staying but would like to see the requirements more precisely defined perhaps by describing with diagrams what would happen to the Layout Table when new columns or rows are added to it, etc.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate is not prejudicial and does not preclude re-opening. (Editing a question automatically flags it for community attention and a re-open vote.) So, pending the improvements @PolyGeo has requested, I will vote to close this thread as a duplicate.

Comment: @PolyGeo In that case I will have to dig a lot deeper into Python scripting than I was hoping (since I don't even understand how it applies to my problem), so I wont pursue this any longer. I was hoping for a native Arcmap solution to link the (image version) of a table in layout view so it gets updated when I change attributes. I don't need to add more features/rows or anything to it, only need cells already there. But since neither of you doesn't seem to know anything about it, I suppose there aren't any easy solutions.