# Update the layout excel file automatically when the attribute table chnages in arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel

I am trying to put an excel table in arcmap layout where this table includes some statistics over one of the Features Attribute table. This Feature is going to be updated regularly and consequently the Excel layout should be updated as well. How can I connect this Excel table to the Feature Attribute to update the statistics automatically.

I have tried to create a GDB table and summerise the Information there but it does not get updated when the Feature informaton changes.

Answer (score 1):

When you add any table to a layout you are simply converting its current content and appearance into a picture.

There is no dynamic link maintained.

There is a possible workaround in the @RyanDalton Answer to this [**Question**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32544/is-it-possible-to-have-a-dynamic-table-in-a-data-driven-page-environment) but is not easy to implement and has some limitations.

Comment: Thank you guys for your guidance and consideration. Well though I am not really expert in ArcGIS but I am assuming there should a way to do this. I would like to know that there is a a way to fill a field of one Feature with statistics over a field of another Feature? for instance, could we say to fill a field with summ of the length of another Feature? I am assuming in this way I can get closer to my aim. I would be really really thankful if somebody couls assist me in this issue.

Comment: Would you perhaps be able to ask this as a new Question?  However, if you do be sure to try and include some diagrams of what you are describing because that is not clear to me from this comment.