# Create a Dynamic Table in your Map Layout - how to use Graphic table element?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, extensions, esri-production-mapping, dynamic-tables

Is [this Solution](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/09/13/create-a-dynamic-table-in-your-map-layout/) (Create a Dynamic Table in your Map Layout using  graphic table element)  is part of [this Extension](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/production-mapping) ESRi production-mapping extension ? how can i use graphic table element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - that solution is part of the Production Mapping (formerly called PLTS) extension.

Otherwise, when you add any table to a layout you are simply converting its current content and appearance into a picture.

There is no dynamic link maintained.

There is a possible workaround in [@RyanDalton's Answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/32609/115) to [Displaying dynamic table in Data Driven Pages environment?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32544) but is not easy to implement and has some limitations.

[My answer to the same question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/282261/115) presents what I believe to be a superior solution, still not easy to implement, that needs only core ArcGIS Pro functionality with a Basic level license.